# What's the right c# syntax for this? return Double[] { 1.0 };

Tags: c#, arrays, return-value

This works:

```
Double[] zeroDist = { 1.0 };
return zeroDist;
```

But I'd like to do it in one line, something like this

```
return Double[] { 1.0 };
```

Comment: @Dai - your statement regarding omitting d seems incorrect as you can see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hiPwJW -  it’s a double literal and you would need to specify the suffix f to make it single

Comment: @RandRandom I eat my words :)

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```cs
return new double[] { 1.0 };
```

Prefer using `double` rather than `Double`. While the two are synonymous, the former is a C# keyword, while the latter is a concrete `struct` type available in the `System` namespace and common for all the languages supported by the CLR.

As noted by @RandRandom, you can also omit the type and the compiler will infer it based on the signature of the function/method:

```cs
double[] Function() => new[] { 1.0 };
```

Comment: Notice: you can omit the type declaration and only use `return new [] { 1.0 };` -  https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYbAD2ArgEYA2ApgNoC66AsgBQCU+hxfUAdnQA7OgHd0zfOjgA6AAzoAvgG5eRJciVA=

Comment: @RandRandom Correct! I have edited the answer.